# JavaFx application with database executable

Tags: java, database

So, i've just finished a small javafX application, with database and stuff... I used Netbeans and **SQl developer**, now i want to export my project so i can use it anywhere i want; any computer,  So, i've tried some programs like Launch4j or something... but the main problem is, even if i make the .exe file, what's gonna happen with the database? it's located in my PC, so if somebody try to use my application, he can't access to the database, so the application won't work...

In other words...What is the solution that i can use to like "Combine" the database with the application, if it is possible? or create the .exe file with the database... I hope that my problem is clear, and thank you for your answers .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as per my understanding you can do two things.

> 1. You can deploy or host your database to any online server and create some web services to fetch and insert data to your application.
> 2. You can create one startup class to create database but here you need to use lite version of database like sql-lite.

if you need more information about sql lite then [click here](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-java/sqlite-jdbc-driver/)

Comment: I used sqlite as embeded database .Thank you.